# Unit test not recognized if i add a generic constrain to the class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, vs-unit-testing-framework

I want to add a generic constraint to my unit test class

```
public class CacheOperationsUnitTests<T>
{
    private ITCache<T> ICacheStore;
    static readonly IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
    static CacheOperationsUnitTests()
    {
        container.RegisterType(typeof(ITCache<>), typeof(TRedisCacheStore<>), (new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager()));
    }

    public CacheOperationsUnitTests()
    {
        ICacheStore = container.Resolve<TRedisCacheStore<T>>();

    }
```

But when I do so, my unit tests are not recognized in the Test Explorer and when I try to run the unit test I get to see this below:

> No test is available in F:\projects\Development VSTO\TRF Dev ( Performance ) New\Perf\SSRProd\Caching.UnitTests\bin\Debug\Caching.UnitTests.dll. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.**

Works fine when I remove the `<T>` from the class name but I need `<T>`
because I need them in my code:

```
private ITCache<T> ICacheStore;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't a *generic constraint* that is hurting you; a generic constraint is the "`where T : SomeWhatever`" part - you don't have that. What is hurting you here is the addition of a *generic type parameter* - i.e. being generic itself.

Imagine you're a test runner. You can see a

```
public class SomeTests<T> {}
```

that has public methods that look like tests. Now; how do you create an instance of that? What `T` do you choose? You can't create an instance of an open generic type - you need a concrete type, like `SomeTests<Bar>` (for some type `Bar`).

One option might be to have:

```
public abstract class CacheOperationsUnitTests<T>
public class FooCacheOperationsUnitTests : CacheOperationsUnitTests<Foo>
public class BarCacheOperationsUnitTests : CacheOperationsUnitTests<Bar>
// plus whatever other T you need
```

However, I strongly suspect you can simply remove  the generics from your test, and use a specific concrete type in place of `T`.